# The right way to save 2 table to access database in vb,net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I tried to save all of records of 2 tables to Access database. My idea is save first table then save next table. But I think it isn't the right way when save multi tables to access because It take a long time.

Here is my code and it run ok but I don't know is there another ways which better to save multi tables to access.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\1_Project\Project_of_VB_Net\AccessDatabase\StudentDatabase.accdb"
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    Dim cmdupdate As String
    Dim cmdinsert As String

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        cmdupdate = "UPDATE StudentData SET ID=@ID, StudentName=@StudentName, StudentID=@StudentID, StudentClass=@StudentClass WHERE StudentID=@StudentID"
        cmdinsert = "INSERT INTO StudentData(ID,StudentName,StudentID,StudentClass) VALUES(@ID,@StudentName,@StudentID,@StudentClass)"
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = cmdupdate
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", dr("ID"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", dr("StudentName"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", dr("StudentID"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentClass", dr("StudentClass"))
        cnn.Open()
        Dim count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If count = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = cmdinsert
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        cnn.Close()
    Next
    For Each dr2 In dt2.Rows
        cmdupdate = "UPDATE StudentData2 SET ID2=@ID2, StudentName2=@StudentName2, StudentID2=@StudentID2, StudentClass2=@StudentClass2 WHERE StudentID2=@StudentID2"
        cmdinsert = "INSERT INTO StudentData2(ID2,StudentName2,StudentID2,StudentClass2) VALUES(@ID2,@StudentName2,@StudentID2,@StudentClass2)"
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = cmdupdate
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID2", dr2("ID2"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName2", dr2("StudentName2"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID2", dr2("StudentID2"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentClass2", dr2("StudentClass2"))
        cnn.Open()
        Dim count2 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If count2 = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = cmdinsert
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        cnn.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a `DataTable` full of data then you don't call `ExecuteNonQuery` in a loop. You call `Update` on a data adapter and save the lot in a single batch.  The `RowState` of each `DataRow` will make the decision to insert or update automatic.

Comment: Check this out:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=

Comment: By the way, why do you have two tables that appear to represent basically the same thing?  It's probably a good bet that you should actually have one table with perhaps an extra Boolean column to indicate whatever it is that you're indicating by using two separate tables.

Comment: You also have a glaring issue with your parameters.  Even though you can use parameter names in your SQL to help you, the ACE OLE DB provider ignores them and uses positional parameters.  In the case of your `UPDATE` statement, you five parameters in the SQL and only add four to the command.  The fact that you have `@StudentID2` in the SQL twice does not mean that you only have to add that parameter once.  It would for SQL Server or another proper database but not for Access.  There's no point setting the `StudentID2` column in that `UPDATE` statement though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry for my late reply. About your first comment, could you please tell me more detail about it. I still not understand your way. I had to use ExecuteNonQuery to check data changed. When it is changed it will use update command, when it isn't changed, it will insert a new row. Your way seem to be a good way but I don't how to use it.

Comment: For your second comment, Actually, 2 table represent for Task_Execute and Task_Review (my daily work). I would like to seperate it 2 table for management

Comment: You don't need two tables in order to manage data. If it's the same data then one table is fine.  Queries have filters for a reason.  Maybe it's appropriate to have two tables but it sounds to me like one table would be more appropriate.  You can simply filter the data for true or false in a Boolean column.

Comment: "About your first comment, could you please tell me more detail about it"  That's why I provided the link.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Let me understand your idea. You mean that I still have 2 for loop, for each loop, I use RowState to check whether row shoud be update or insert and then I should use da.update(mytable) instead of ExecuteNonQuery, doesn't it?

Comment: 1 tables for "task_Execute" and "task_review" is probably better. But now I think when I display data. I will use filter "Boolean column" to check if it = 1 then show record to listbox 1, if it = 0 show record to listbox 2. But I cannot find any command like "Select * with filter..."

Comment: You can use two queries to populate two `DataTables` and just change the `WHERE` clause. Alternatively, you could retrieve all the data with one query into one `DataTable` and bind that to two `BindingSources` with different `Filter` property values. You can then bind those to different controls. The advantage of the latter option is that you can simply change the value in the column you're filtering on and you'll see the record move from one list to the other.

Comment: I understood your idea now. It's probable better than because each table have many field, So, I will use SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Boolean_Column = 1, like this? Let me try with it and so many thank to you for attempt to help :)